# ReactJS how to limit the input value inline?

Tags: html, reactjs, input

I need to limit the possible input values to [0,1,2] but I would really like to do it inline to avoid further issues with my code.

This is my input :

```
<input
 className="form-control"
 name="labelPred1"
 type="text"
 value={this.state.jsondata.prediction2[k]}
 onChange={e => this.onPred2Change(k, e.target.value)}
/>
```

I think it won't be possible to do it inline because with my research I found that I should check the content using `.match(regex)` in my `onPred2Change()` function, but maybe someone know how to do that directly in the `<input>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it needs to be a text input and it's not only numbers in a specific order. You can use the [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute that works with most [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/input-pattern).

Example:

```html
<form>
Numbers: <input pattern="\d*" required title="Numbers only, please." /><br />
Specified values (0,1 or 3): <input pattern="[0,1,3]" required title="0, 1 or 3" /><br />
<button type="submit">Validate and send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Or I don't understand or something is strange but I can't put whatever I want in both fields

Comment: @J.erome you are able to enter whatever value you want. But when you submit and validate the form, it will only accept the specified patterns.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a number, check out html `input` tag `max` and `min` values:

```
 <input type="number" min="0" max="2">
```

Comment: But if the user select it with his mouse he can set 55 for example :(

Comment: as ZarX said in his answer, you should validate the input before submitting it.